# Interaction between MQL5 (or C++) and C# via Named Pipes

Tags: c#, c++, pipe, named-pipes, mql5

I am trying to send some data via Named Pipes. I created Named Pipe Server in C# and client in MQL5 (it is just a C++ wrapper). Server works fine and can be reached from Named Pipe Client written in C# so communication **C# <-> C# works fine**. Also i tried utility PipeList and it also shows that my pipe server is visible and available.

The only problem is with client written in MQL5 (C++) - it does not find the path to the pipe server so communication **MQL <-> C# is failing**.

Could anybody suggest :

- what am i doing wrong?
- how to check that both C# and MQL are accessing the same physical
  path and the same location?

**Server :**

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("MQL5", PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte)
```

I also tried full path \\\\.\\pipe\\MQL5 with no success

**Client :**

```
CFilePipe iPipe;

while(IsStopped() == false)
{
    Print("This loop is infinite because there is no connection");
    if (iPipe.Open("\\\\.\\pipe\\MQL5", FILE_READ | FILE_WRITE | FILE_BIN) != INVALID_HANDLE) break;
    Sleep(250);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is found. Seems that was simply my own mistake or this is how Pipes work in MQL - channel always needs to be Duplex so line in C# needs to be replaced with the following :

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(name, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte)
```

Parameter PipeDirection.**InOut** says pipe to be two-way.

P.S. Though it is a little weird anyway because conjunction C# Server <-> C# Client can work in both modes (In / Out or one of them)

Comment: have you succeeded with this integration? This code is github or somewhere else? Thanks

Comment: @LeoPucciBr : you may want to check this repository, it should be publicly available https://bitbucket.org/artemiusgreat/examples

Comment: Folder MT5 Tester, not sure if it works now, didn't check this project for at least last half a year, some changes might happen in MetaTrader since then, e.g. MT5 now supports virtual deals that allows to have to opposite positions at the same time ... anyway, yuo're free to use this script as an idea :)

Answer (score 1):

**Server:** C# / **Client:** MetaTrader

I had two other problems:

1. The client and server needed to be run as Administrator
2. I needed to set buffer size for input and ouput (Default is zero => 
   dynamically calculated => there was an error on this).